# Should reputation be kept for answers deleted for plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers, plagiarism

I recently custom flagged an answer on a popular post for directly plagiarizing the accepted answer. The flag was accepted and the answer deleted.

However, the answer had collected enough upvotes and been around long enough to have its [reputation retained](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

What should (and can) be done in cases like these? Should I mention it in my flag? Do moderators even have the power to override this bug/feature?

Since the answer has been deleted it can't even be downvoted any more. Deleting seems almost like a reward for a bad post when it means keeping reputation and downvote immunity.

Comment: Moderators can request that the post is disassociated from the account.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a lot of effort involved there? That sounds like a process.

Comment: I've looked at the post; that wasn't as clear-cut a case as I'd normally request disassociation for. The score is low enough that I'd just leave it be.

Comment: Yes, it's a process, we request that a Community Manager does this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yea, I was gonna say that sounds like too much work for the (fairly trivial) case that lead me to post this. Useful to know for future though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can request that a Community Manager disassociates the post from an account. This then also removes the votes received for that post from the account.

It is up to the moderator handling a flag to decide whether or not to also request a disassociation.

I've used this in the past to revert the reputation gain from clear plagiarism cases.